# Convert dateTime to written date and time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I have a dateTime string that looks like this:

```
"2016-07-13T09:00:00.000-0700"
```

And the date and time formats I need are:

```
"July 13, 2016" and "9:00 AM"
```

Does anyone know of a package I can use to take care of this, or have some advice on how to go about writing something for this?

Comment: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/ look at this link

Comment: There are many, many questions here on [*parsing*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+parse+a+date) and [*formatting*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date) dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that will do almost everything you want with a date, for your case look at the `.format` method.

You can also convert it to a Date `new Date("2016-07-13T09:00:00.000-0700")` then use [the methods in the Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date) to do it yourself. But it will not be as easier as with moment.

Comment: My advice: jump straight to using Moment: it's the Javascript date formatting standard for a reason.  Javascript's core date methods are inconsistent, confusing, and lack significant functionality.

Comment: Saying "use library X" isn't an answer, it should be a comment. The question is off–topic precisely because the type of answer it encourages will be suggestions to use different libraries rather than how to fix a specific issue with code.

Comment: @RobG well the question is "Does anyone know of a package", so a library is really what was asked here, no? I'm sure sure why do you say it's not an answer

Comment: [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*"

Comment: Ho right I forgot about that, thanks for the reminder.